# Jenkins: Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built - with different .m2 location(s)?

Tags: maven, jenkins, triggers, dependencies

In Jenkins, we configured different maven jobs. Each of those jobs installs their result build artefact to one of some local *.m2* repositories being different to the default local *.m2* repository (e. g. *.m2-dev*, specified in the *settings.xml* that are specified by the *-s* flag in the job's *maven goals*).

Now, when using the *"Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"* option, it seems that dependent builds are only triggered if content (.jar) changes in the default *.m2* repository are detected.

**My question:** Is it possible to specify an alternative *.m2* settings file or repository location for a job that the *"Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"* will be aware of?

Thank you for any hints or alternative suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a repository manager?

Comment: We have a repo manager (Apache Archiva) that we use to hold the deployed artifact builds built from master branch. But, in the current scenario we dont use it: We only want to build and install (not deploy) SNAPSHOTs to a developer-specific local repo on our integration server. This is necessary to avoid conflicts when building artifacts with same version but built from different branches.

Comment: Generally, I would think about using different names for artifacts from other branches to avoid confusion. A different approach would be to have separate repositories in your repository manager to distinguish the two "areas".

Comment: @JFabianMeier: Thanks for the ideas. Using different names for artifacts doesn't integrate well in our current settings, we already thought about that too. The approach with different repos has IMO the advantage that no further (version name) adaptions in pom.xml are required. Most of the things work already well by using the -s flag in the jobs that we use to build our .jars and .wars, but the problem is still that relevant dependent jobs are currently not triggered. One alternative would be to setup different jenkins instances but I'm still trying to avoid that.

Comment: Different versions is the option instead of changing the name...

Comment: If you use different versions on the branch accordingly to the ticket you are working on it's very clear where a version belongs to...and you can use the usual setup and deploy to your repository manager...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Ok, I see the advantage of using branch-specific artefact version identifiers. On the other side, I think it would take additional effort to manage dependency resolution in such way that at the end "the right .jar will be part of the resulting .war". Of course, we could define branch-specific dependencies in the top level project to ensure that it will be contained in the effective pom, but currently there is no need to to so. And the other thing is that we don't need developer artefacts to get into remote repository at all (then, of course, unique artefacts would be required).

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your structure to a multi module build instead..

Comment: For each dependency we have a separate repo and a corresponding jenkins job for building .jar artefacts (by configuration from master or a certain branch). Same for (single or multimodule) projects building the .war's that depend on some of those .jars. I'm not sure how I could change this structure to a multi module build. Could you please explain this a bit more?